# Scilab Character Recognition Creating Database File

Tags: character, ocr, scilab

I am using Character Recognition Examples below link.
https://fileexchange.scilab.org/toolboxes/133000

But I want to change the database. 
(Current Database file in net.dat)

Where can I find images which are used to create database in this
example and how to create net.dat from Images ?

What will be size of Image, B/W , BMP or GIF or extra..?

I need to change database from Detecting some Hardware Alphanumeric
charactors.

I am trying to create database as Below in Scilab.
Image for Handwritten..

```
a= imread('D:\01.bmp');
b= imread('D:\trial dat\02.bmp');
c= imread('D:\trial dat\11.bmp');
d= imread('D:\trial dat\12.bmp');
e= imread('D:\trial dat\21.bmp');
f= imread('D:\trial dat\22.bmp');
g= imread('D:\trial dat\31.bmp');
h= imread('D:\trial dat\32.bmp');
i= imread('D:\trial dat\41.bmp');
j= imread('D:\trial dat\42.bmp');
k= imread('D:\trial dat\51.bmp');
l= imread('D:\trial dat\52.bmp');
m= imread('D:\trial dat\61.bmp');
n= imread('D:\trial dat\62.bmp');
save('D:\try.dat',a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n);
```

Database Size is too big as from Orignal Database in Example.
Unable to recoginze Character as per New Database.

Comment: did you try coding by own?

Comment: Yes.  I am tried  as below but a= imread('D:\01.bmp');
b= imread('D:\trial dat\02.bmp');
c= imread('D:\trial dat\11.bmp');
d= imread('D:\trial dat\12.bmp');
e= imread('D:\trial dat\21.bmp');
f= imread('D:\trial dat\22.bmp');
g= imread('D:\trial dat\31.bmp');
h= imread('D:\trial dat\32.bmp');
i= imread('D:\trial dat\41.bmp');
j= imread('D:\trial dat\42.bmp');
k= imread('D:\trial dat\51.bmp');
l= imread('D:\trial dat\52.bmp');
m= imread('D:\trial dat\61.bmp');
n= imread('D:\trial dat\62.bmp');
save('D:\net.dat',a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n);  Save dat file then load

Comment: edit your question and add code to that

Comment: Do you know how the original net.dat was created? Maybe your way of saving is not correct. From the `pbRecognize_callback` function (`load('net.dat'); [y,ind]=max(ann_FF_sim(net,handles.charvec2'));`) it seems that it expects one variable named `net`, not `a`, `b`, `c`... And also check the type of the original net variable (what `size`, is it a `list`, what type: i.e. `uint8` or other, etc)

Comment: Hello Attila, Thanks for update. But Don't know how original database is created. But How to create Load file I followed below link. help.scilab.org/doc/5.3.3/en_US/load.htmlOriginal datasize in 16.7KB Only.. What should I do ?